# Objective-C return subclass based on Xcode project target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, subclass, superclass

I have my Xcode project up to compile for two targets, for the sake of simplicity we'll call them 'Foo' and 'Bar'. I have a superclass and two subclasses, how can I cleanly ensure that a variable is returned as a different subclass based on the project target?

So for example, say I have the following...

```
ViewManager.h //Super Class
FooViewManager.h //Foo Subclass
BarViewManager.h //Bar Subclass

...

ViewManager * viewManager;

#if Target_Foo

    viewManager = [[FooViewManager alloc] init];

#elif Target_Bar

    viewManager = [[BarViewManager alloc] init];

#else

    viewManager = [[ViewManager alloc] init];

#endif

...
```

Is there any way I can make this code cleaner, so in the caller class I dont need all the compiler `#if` statements, and I only have to initialize the superclass, and maybe the superclass init method can take care of switching based on the current project target, and return the correct subclass within my `viewManager` variable?

I'm sure there's probably a standard pattern for doing this in Objective-C that i'm missing, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to locate required subclass definition in one place, i.e., you could make define once and use it all over the places:

```
#if defined(Target_Foo)
    #define CurrentViewManager FooViewManager
#elif defined(Target_Bar)
    #define CurrentViewManager BarViewManager
#else
    #define CurrentViewManager ViewManager
#endif
```

And then just use this new define everywhere without preprocessor macros:

```
CurrentViewManager *manager = [[CurrentViewManager alloc] init];
```

Probably you find it useful to incapsulate this logic in some fabric method:

```
+ (ViewManager *)createViewManager
{
    // Preprocessor switches would be here
    // ...

    return [[CurrentViewManager alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 identically-named classes and assign the m resource files to different targets. This way you can declare a general type in the h file but under the hood the compiler will use 2 different source files for its implementation.

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility however this wouldn't allow me to have one 'SuperClass' with a default implementation and only override specific methods within that class. It would require duplication of the entire class code, even if there was only a small change required in one of the 'target' classes.

Comment: you can make the superclass on both targets and the subclasses on individual targets